# Updating link_to data params with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a link_to in rails that I want to use Jquery to update some of the data params.

```
<script>
  $('#filterrific_results').find('.btn').on('click', function(){
    var patient_id = $(this).attr('data-patient_id');
    var templates = $('.modal-body').find('a');
    templates.attr('patient_id', patient_id);
  })
</script>
```

I've tried this way:

```
<%= link_to new_assessment_path(:template_id => template.id, :patient_id => "") do %>
```

But the code doesn't seem to work because I'm adding the data attribute after the href url has already been rendered by rails.

I've also tried:

```
 <%= link_to new_assessment_path, {:controller => "assessments", :action => "new", :template => template.id, :patient_id=> patient.id} do %>
```

But no luck either. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're getting some things mixed up. `data` attributes are the ones which have `data-` prefix in their pure `html` representation:

```
// NOTE: data-spacing, data-sowing-time are data attributes
<li id="my_li" data-spacing="10cm" data-sowing-time="March to June">Carrots</li>
```

Their value can be obtained and changed using [jQuery .data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
// NOTE: this made data-spacing data attribute set up to 20cm
$('#my_li').data('spacing', "20cm")
```

`link_to` helper does not use `data` attribute to set up your link path (as `<a>` tag already has its `href` attribute for that purpose). So what you end up calling your `link_to` is something like:

```
// link_to "New assesment", new_assessment_path(:template_id => 4)
<a href="/assesments/new?template_id=4">
```

If I understand correctly, your aim is to change the `href` which link points to. In this case you could achieve it by either changing `href` attribute...

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.yourdomain.com/assesments/new?template_id=205")
```

or by handling your link clicking manually:

```
<%= link_to "New assesment", "#", :id => "new_assesment", :"data-template-id" => 4 %>

<script>
  $('#new_assesment').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    path_template = "http://yourdomain.com/assesments/new?template_id=";
    param_id = $('#new_ass').data('template-id');
    window.location.href = path_template + param_id;
});
</script>
```

which gives you an opportunity to use `jQuery .data()` function mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can assign data attribute using `link_to`

```
= link_to "Test", root_path, id: "data-example", data: { hello: "World" }
```

So if you want to set `patient_id` data attribute,

```
<%= link_to new_assessment_path(:template_id => template.id), data: { :patient_id => "" } %>
```

From jQuery, you can update it as,

```
templates.attr('data-patient-id', patient_id);
```

Note that `data-patient-id` is hyphen-seperated.